# Would you like a subject class for semigroup theory on the arXiv?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, journals, math-communication, arxiv

After contacting the arxiv recently about possibly adding semigroup theory as a subject class, they suggested I canvas the research community to establish whether such a subject class would be used and whether there's enough support available for moderation etc..

I have created an email address and website as an attempt to allow members of the semigroup community to indicate whether they would likely submit papers under the subject class were it created and/or indicate whether they are able to offer support for moderation etc.. The website is available at https://arxiv-semigroup-theory-class.gitlab.io with the email address listed on the website.

It would be excellent if people from the research community could consider their own commitments there and to possibly pass the url around with other members from the semigroup theory research community (probably better someone has this pointed out to them several times rather than not at all).

Comment: What would you count as semigroup theory? Using semigroups to study other objects or studying semigroups in their own right?

Comment: Personally I would class studying semigroups in their own right as semigroup theory then using semigroups to study other things under whatever those other things are. For example I have a game theory paper (available on my personal site and arxiv) that uses a lot of group theory, but I would not call it a paper in group theory.

Comment: What would be the reason to start a new subject class? There are many active research areas that do not have their own subject class (e.g. arithmetic geometry, geometric analysis, and geometric group theory) where research is posted to a larger subject class (e.g. algebraic geometry or number theory; differential geometry or analysis of PDEs; and algebraic topology or group theory, respectively). There are usually reasons to keep it this way (e.g. backwards compatibility, audience size and make-up, etc).

Comment: There isn't really an appropriate larger category to submit to, except maybe general mathematics (which I don't see as an ideal place to submit semigroup theory papers to) and I am pretty sure the current norm is to submit to something similar like group theory or combinatorics (my game theory paper was shoved in to combinatorics rather than cs and game theory, which is in my opinion a misclassification).

Comment: An alternative could be to change the [description](https://arxiv.org/archive/math) of the subject class Group Theory to say explicitly something like 'Groups and group-like structures'. In any classification system, there is a trade-off between accuracy and usefulness.

Comment: If there was an algebra classification that could be used however there isn't one. Another option would be to propose an algebra subject classification rather than semigroup theory, however semigroup theory is similar in level with grouping to the other classifications rather than having things as general as alebgra/analysis as subject classes.

Comment: The description at https://arxiv.org/archive/math includes “semigroups” under the subject class Rings and Algebras.

Comment: I didn't know it was listed under rings and algebras. While it is typically quite normal to look at semigroup algebras, not sure I like shoving all semigroup theory under that classification. Much like how people look at group algebras yet there is also a subject class for group theory (and semigroup theory will likely always be more vast than group theory).

Comment: I think it would generally help to have fine-grained classes (closer to AMS MSC) on the arXiv, as opposed to their current 2-letter classifiers. This is particularly egregious in math.CO, which is sending some 40 new papers into my mailbox every workday, with less than 1/3 of them relevant to my interest! math.RA is almost quaint in comparison.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to look at MathSciNet/Zbmath and try to get a relative count of papers with the relevant MSC codes?  Then perhaps do the same for some existing subject classes, for comparison.  That might be stronger quantitative evidence than "some people on MO thought it was a good idea".

Comment: I think it would be helpful if Arxiv put semigroups with groups like mathscinet  does. They put it with rings and algebras because I suspect algebras was initially intended to include universal algebras rather than just algebras over rings. But it is confusing since group theory tends to be closer in spirit to semigroups.

Comment: I agree that semigroup theory better fits in the Group Theory class than in the Rings and Algebra class. Not only because semigroup theory is close to group theory in many respects (and each one feeds of each other, when not just indiscernible), but also because the class Rings and Algebras is somewhat poorly defined.